# Безопасно ли использовать класс PlayerPrefs в Unity для хранения данных?

Tags: unity3d

Безопасно ли использовать встроенный класс PlayerPrefs в Unity для хранения, скажем, данных о внутриигровой валюте? Есть ли возможность изменять значение ключа "извне"?

Comment: `Есть ли возможность изменять значение ключа "извне"?` - легко. допустим игра на десктопе. я открываю реестр, правлю значение..всё.................... если игра standalone, на одного человека, типа побегал пострелял, то если почитерил - и бог с ним...... но если это критичный момент в игре, который нужен для взаимодействия с другими игроками, их операциями - то 100% надо хранить данные на сервере

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Окей, с десктопом все понял, а как с мобильными устройствами? И есть ли возможность реализовать защиту без хранения данных на сервере? Можно ли сериализовать данные, и только после этого писать, например?

Comment: десктоп или мобильное устройство — не важно. сломать на клиенте можно всё. путей для этого много. `И есть ли возможность реализовать защиту без хранения данных на сервере?` - как вы думаете, банковские данные и внутренние счета людей хранятся на сервере или на клиенте?)) `Можно ли сериализовать данные, и только после этого писать, например?` - сериализация как тут поможет? это же не шифрование. ..... ну ок. вы зашифровали, записали...я взял ваш код (или например apk под андройд), декомпильнул, увидел как это делается, расшифровал, заменил.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Ну с банками все понятно, там защита нужна по-наджнее) А что насчет проверки по хеш-суммам? Может спасти от желающих засунть нос куда не надо?) Хотя бы от не совсем умелых желающих.

Comment: `Хотя бы от не совсем умелых желающих` ... я не понимаю. совсем не умелые не смогут сунуть нос, а другие - мухлюйте с валютой, делайте бесконечные суммы, скупайте всё, пофиг, вы достойны этого! Так чтоли?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Для первого проекта начинающей инди-студии держать сервер или даже использовать какой-нибудь azure довольно затратно. Соответственно, хочется найти некий баланс по соотношению затраты\качество защиты. Если не утрировать, то да, я допускаю, что какой-то процент игроков будет успешно "взламывать" игру и моя задача - свести этот процент к минимум при минимальном количестве финансовых и, так сказать, архитектурных  затрат. Я бы вам порекомендовал оформить ваши комментарии в один полноценный ответ, ибо он будет весьма полезен.

Comment: Какие у меня, как у хакера, есть возможности оповестить мир о своём великом прогрессе? Если никаких (игра-песочница), то и забейте. Пусть себе что хотят взламывают, никто их достижений всё равно не увидит. Если есть какой-нибудь лидерборд, то нужно хранить в этом лидерборде рядом с прогрессом, число приобретённой валюты и валидировать число набранного рейтинга исходя из валюты в наличии.

Comment: @vp_arth Никаких лидербордов или чего-то подобного не предусмотрено, но есть внутриигровая валюта, которую хочется хоть каким-то образом обезопасить)